# Replacing HTML content stopped other jquery events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to wrap all occurrence of registered (®) with the  tag..

I am using the below jquery as solution:

```
$("p,h1,h2,h3,h4,li,a").each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/&reg;/gi, '<sup>&reg;</sup>').replace(/®/gi, '<sup>&reg;   </sup>'));
});
```

It work fine but facing issue like other events which are bind to element are not working.

Any solution or work around to add  tag around all registered symbol (®) without losing other events.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're rewriting the elements by using `.html()`, and so any events attached to them are lost. If you switched your handlers to instead use [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), they would not be lost when recreating the elements.